# How to save data in a session?

Tags: php

How to save data in a session and when the page is reloaded shows the current and previous ones?

Each time I add a student or surcharge the page the previously added student disappears.

```
include_once("student.php");

class Secretary{

    public $students = array();

}

$secretary = new Secretary();

// Add students.
$student = new student($_POST['name'],$_POST['lastname']);
array_push($secretary->students,$student);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP sessions is pretty simple, you can find more info on sessions in these 2 links:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

You need to make sure that `session_start();` is called on every page you want to use sessions. This only needs to be done once and is generally put at the top of the page, or put inside a config file that is included on every page.

You can then use:

```
$_SESSION['Secretary'] = $secretary->students;
// this will store your array
```

Then to ensure you have the array on a page reload you could use the `__construct` function in your class.

```
function __construct(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['Secretary']) && is_array($_SESSION['Secretary'])){
        $this->students = $_SESSION['Secretary'];          
    }
}
```

Altogether you would have as script the looks like:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("student.php");

class Secretary{

    public $students = array();

    function __construct(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['Secretary']) && is_array($_SESSION['Secretary'])){
            $this->students = $_SESSION['Secretary'];          
        }
    }

}

$secretary = new Secretary();

// Add students.
$student = new student($_POST['name'],$_POST['lastname']);
array_push($secretary->students,$student);
$_SESSION['Secretary'] = $secretary->students;

?>
```